application method cannot be found in gradle build file in intellij idea
I'm trying to run an old java project that was developed about six years ago. I just ran "./gradle dependencies" to see if I have the necessary tools, turns out I don't have the wrapper script. I ran the command "gradle wrapper" to create a wrapper script but I'm getting an error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file '/path-to-project/build.gradle' line: 19

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.



Could not find method application() for arguments [build_r247umzyolj2n9s39yj76bis$_run_closure3@43cff6e9] on root project 'project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

and this is my gradle build file :
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()  // Ensure this connects to Maven Central to fetch dependencies
}

dependencies {
    // Existing dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.12'  // Example
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'  // Example utility

    // JavaFX dependencies
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:21'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.hms.hms_test_2.MainApp'
}

what is wrong guys????
